# Meteor scraping, HTTP.post resulting with damaged PDF in response.content

Tags: pdf, meteor, screen-scraping

The `HTTP.post` which I use to scrape a web site for a .PDF file returns a damaged file which is full of `3F` characters displayed as question marks.

For example, in a given saved file I have

> %PDF-1.4����

instead of

> %PDF-1.4\C8\D2\F0\FE

Any ideas what might be the solution to this problem?

Comment: I improved the readability of the question and introduced quote sections around the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with Request (npm install request) and right combination of options. Used Iron router for displaying of the pdf.

```
let responseRoute = this.response;
let request = require('request');
request({
    method: "POST",
    url: doc_url,
    headers: headers,
    form: payload,
    body: Buffer,
    encoding: null,
    gzip: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    responseRoute.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
        "Content-Length": body.length,
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment",
    });
    responseRoute.write(body);
    responseRoute.end();
});}, {
    where: "server"
});
```